# Есть ли в C# аналоги иницализаторов, которые могут заменить конструктор?

Tags: c#

В C++ есть очень похожая конструкция, то есть, иногда хочется написать что то типа такого:

```
    public class Book {
        public string Title;
        public Book(string name) : Title=name{}
    }
```

Ну, то есть, я какие то простые присваивания пишу ВНЕ КОНСТРУКТОРА, и работать они будут до того, как начнёт выполняться конструктор.

Я посмотрел - везде пишут про "инициализаторы полей", то есть про что то типа `public string Title = "Хорошая книга!";`

Нет ли такого синтаксиса в C#?

Если такого нет - ничего страшного, просто хочу понять, есть такое в синтаксисе языка или нет.

Спасибо заранее за подсказки.

Про то, что можно простые штуки заменить на лямбды, например, так

```
    public class Book {
        public string Title;
        public Book(string name) => Title = name;
    }
```

я уже знаю.

Comment: Все инициаторы полей вне конструктора на самом деле инлайнятся во ВСЕ конструкторы, в самое начало. Т.е. выполняются после конструктора базового типа, но до кода в конструкторе

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: @AzizUmarov - спасибо, кажется, я перепутал синтакиси инициализации с синтаксисом обращения к конструктору базового класса...

Comment: `=> Title = name` — это не лямбда (то есть, не анонимная внутренняя функция), это альтернативная форма записи `{ Title = name; }`.

Comment: @VladD - спасибо, это справедливо, просто не хватает слов :-) и хочется лямбдой назвать всё, что содержит стрелку =>

Comment: Похожее на то, о чём вы говорите, есть тут: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#positional-records